# how do you interpret the d3 event.x and event.y coordinates?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to implement drag events in d3 (v6.2), and I'm having some trouble interpreting the d3 x and y coordinates. Consider the following code. When I inspect the console output, it seems to me like, in the drag handler:

- `event.x` and `event.y` are the SUM of the user (graph) coordinate object locations and the total movement/distance in SVG coordinates?
- `event.dx` and `event.dy` are indicator that tell you whether since the last update, you've moved left/up (-1), not moved (0), or right/down (1)?
- `event.subject.x` and `event.subject.y` give the location of the object being dragged?
- if I want the current coordinates of the drag (either in user/graph coordinates or SVG coordinates), I need to calculate them myself (see example in code, which seems to work)?

I can't find where the specifics of this are documented. My questions are:

1. Are the above impressions correct?
2. If not correct, what's the best way to get the current drag coordinates?
3. If correct, why would one SUM the values from two different coordinate systems? That doesn't make sense to me.

```html
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>

<style>
circle.circ {
  fill: red;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
</style>

<script>

function dragHandler(e, d){
    
    const objx = scaleX.invert(e.x - d.x + scaleX(d.x))
    const objy = scaleY.invert(e.y - d.y + scaleY(d.y))

    console.log(`x: ${e.x}, dx: ${e.dx} sx: ${e.subject.x} objx: ${objx}\ny: ${e.y} dy: ${e.dy} sy: ${e.subject.y} objy: ${objy}`)
}

var drag = d3
 .drag()
 .on('drag', dragHandler)

var x = [{x: 150, y: 150}]

var svg = d3.select("svg")

var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 80,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 50
}
var width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right
var height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom

g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

var scaleX = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]).domain([140, 160])
var scaleY = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).domain([140, 160])

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(scaleX));

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(scaleY))

var circ = g.selectAll(".circ")
  .data(x)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return scaleX(d.x) })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return scaleY(d.y) })
  .attr("class", "circ")
  .call(drag);

</script>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: The documentation is a bit obscure but you can find it [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: I had seen that but the table just says "See drag.container" and then in that section, it says "[t]he container of a drag gesture determines the coordinate system of subsequent drag events, affecting event.x and event.y" which is not clear to me - it doesn't say how it affects it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your impression is right. You can either

- compute the distance in local coordinates as the difference between `event.x/y` and `event.subject.x/y`

- retrieve the screen distance with [`event.clickDistance()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/README.md#drag_clickDistance) as a getter

These two work in different coordinate systems.

- The **client coordinate system** is that of the browser viewport. They are just read from the native DOM `mousemove` event.
- The **user coordinate system** is the one of the thing being dragged, using the same coordinates as those used when writing SVG markup. They are computed from the client coordinates with a [transform matrix](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/types.html#__svg__SVGGraphicsElement__getScreenCTM) the SVG API provides. The source code is [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/pointer.js).

What you did was the in-between way that normally is not needed: by applying the `scaleX/Y` transform, you computed the coordinates in the system of the **SVG viewBox**, i. e. the coordinate system that is found when the `viewBox` is applied to the outermost `<svg>` element. That can be the client coordinate system, but only if the attribute is not set, or the `width` and `height` values of the element match the contents of the `viewBox`.

In almost every practical use case, the two will differ. The "Scalable" in SVG [is just about that distinction](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/). Leaving out the `viewBox` like you did deprives you of the possibility to easily scale your grafic as a whole.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm still not clear on why one would add coordinates from two systems? One of the reasons I'm doing it this way is I want to limit the drag based on the graph coordinates (e.g., can't drag the shape below x=145). Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @ccprog's answer above ( that worked for me ). It is also useful to add `.container(selection.node)` to your `drag` object. This makes the coordinates work well. Pay attention not to pass the `selection` but the `selection.node()` to `.container(...)`.